# How to test a conditional expression in mocha / sinon

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I have some function like this:

```
abc(prop) {
      const x = aComplexFunction(this.productData, 'productStatus');
      let result;

      /* istanbul-ignore-next */
      if (x) {
        const key = (x[prop]) ? 'enabled' : 'notEnabled';

        result = `wayOfLife.${key}`;
      }

      return result;
    },
```

My coverage says the 'enabled' part is not covered. How to fix this

Answer (score 1):

To cover the `'enabled'` case you just need a test case where the `x[prop]` is truthy.

An easy way to do that is to use something like `'toString'` since `toString` exists on every object as the [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function and functions evaluate to be truthy.

Here is a slightly simplified working example to demonstrate:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const aComplexFunction = () => ({});

function abc(prop) {
  const x = aComplexFunction();
  let result;

  if (x) {
    const key = (x[prop]) ? 'enabled' : 'notEnabled';
    result = `wayOfLife.${key}`;
  }

  return result;
};

it('will cover the enabled case', function() {
  expect(abc('propThatDoesNotExist')).to.equal('wayOfLife.notEnabled');  // <= covers notEnabled
  expect(abc('toString')).to.equal('wayOfLife.enabled');  // <= covers enabled
});
```